# Can we map one source to Mutiple Destination Tables in BizTalk Services?

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-services

We have a scenario where we will be receiving an Xml Source File as below

```
<Client>
    <ClientAddress>
     <ClientCode>123</ClientCode>
    <ClientDBName>asdf</ClientDBName>
    <ClientFEIN>asdf</ClientFEIN>
    <ClientName>asdf</ClientName>
    <ComplexityLevel>asdf</ComplexityLevel>
    <EftpsPIN>asdf</EftpsPIN>
      <Address>
        <City>Test City</City>
        <ClientCode>Test Code</ClientCode>
        <Description>Test Desc</Description>
        <State>Test Sta</State>
        <Stree2>Test Stree2</Stree2>
        <Street1>Test Stree1</Street1>
        <UseAsDefault>false</UseAsDefault>
        <ZipCode>1245</ZipCode>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <City>asdf</City>
        <ClientCode>asdf</ClientCode>
        <Description>asdf</Description>
        <State>asdf</State>
        <Stree2>asdf</Stree2>
        <Street1>asdf</Street1>
        <UseAsDefault>false</UseAsDefault>
        <ZipCode>1255</ZipCode>
      </Address>
    </ClientAddress>       
  </Client>
```

The destination is Azure Sql Server Database with two tables Client and ClientAddress.
But I am struck with  mapping to two tables with one source.

is there any way to map directly?
I am done with mapping from one source to one destination but our scenario is one source to multiple destinations, can this be possible. 
please help me I am very new to BizTalk and BizTalk services

I am working on Biztalk Services with azure Databases

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please clear out if you are using BizTalk Server with MS SQL Server or BizTalk Services with SQL Azure databases? This is not clear in your question or tags. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.BizTalk Services with SQL Azure Database

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to pass the XML to a stored procedure, but then the stored procedure will have to use OpenXML to parse the XML, since you have a one to many relationship.

A better alternative might be to call a WCF webservice that puts the data in SQL.

A third alternatives is to have two maps, and two send ports, but that's not ideal, because one of the parent relationships might fail, causing the child relationships to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use debatching? Make the schema for the message that you have an envelope schema and create a new one for Address - this way you can have a send port that deals only with address and another one that deals with the client.